# Python 3.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, python-3.x

I've spent some time today playing with getting the source for python 3.1.1 to build on my MacBook Pro using the --enable-framework and --enable-universalsdk options with no success. I will humbly admit that I have no real clue why I can't compile 3.1.1 on Snow Leopard, I did make sure to get the new Xcode version for Snow Leopard, and made sure I also installed the 10.4u SDK. It seems to be choking on the 10.4 SDK during the make stage, and has several error regarding headers for wchar, cursor, and ncursor during the configure stage. I have been able to get a make from a plain configure, and most the test pass, but that just isn't challenging enough. Has anyone else attempted to build python 3.1.1 on a Mac running Snow Leopard

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you aren't using the Mac installer disk image at http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.1.1/python-3.1.1.dmg ?

Comment: Or why not use MacPorts (http://www.macports.org)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an automated installer here: http://python.org/ftp/python/3.1.1/python-3.1.1.dmg

Answer (score 1):

You need to set MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET if you actually want to use an older SDK.

If you target 10.6, it may be that PPC building is not supported anymore, according to [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue6245). In fact, that may be the case even if you target 10.4, using XCode 3.2 (haven't tried myself).

Comment: I agree, you've stated a much more eloquent version of my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have 10.6 installed yet so I can't say for sure it will work without issue but, in general, if you want to build a batteries-included framework build optimized for 10.6 of Python on OS X, you're best off using the installer build script in the source tree at `Mac/BuildScript/build-installer.py` after applying [the patch](http://bugs.python.org/file14237/arch-intel.patch) in the bug report Martin referred to.  Something like this should work [untested]:

.`/build-installer.py --sdk-path=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk --universal-archs=intel --dep-target=10.6 --src-dir=... --build-dir=...`

That will build everything including dependent third-party libraries and the documentation but, be forewarned, you'll probably have to tweak things until you get it right and a few things aren't supported yet in 64-bit, most notably, tkinter. As mentioned above, the standard python.org 3.1.1 installer *should* likely work OK as long as you don't need 64-bit support.

[EDIT: I should clarify that, WRT 64-bit support, the problem isn't in tkinter, rather that the Apple-supplied versions of Tk in 10.5 and earlier were 32-bit only and so there was code in setup.py to prevent attempting to build a 64-bit version of tkinter on OSX.  Perhaps that check can be removed now if the 10.6 Tk is 64-bit.]

Answer (score 0):

Kenneth Reitz's soluton doesn't work for me. In fact, the install works fine but my default `PATH` still points to `/usr/bin/python` (v2.6.1.). I vaguely recall that we should be modifying our `~/.profile` to point to `/.../Frameworks` and I expected the installer to do this for me (nope).

Anyway, `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin` exists so we could add it.
But I'm curious why the python bin in there does a crash and burn on me.

No time to resolve this now. Bye.

Comment: I finally gave in used the installer and had this same issue. Then while reading through some documentation somewhere I realized that the installer was not modifying the profile automatically like it normally does.